# Grails - How to replace attribute before the query?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following:

```
 myQuery { Map paramsMap, List<MyObject> objectList = null ->
            and {
                if (paramsMap.firstName) {
                    ilike('firstName', paramsMap.firstName + "%")
                }
                if (paramsMap.phone) {
                    ilike('phone', paramsMap.phone + "%")
                }
            }
 }
```

It's working fine. The problem is that the phone can be stored as 123-123-1234 or 9876543210.

When we got to the search screen, if user looks for 1231231234, he'll get no results because the person saved the phone number with dashes. And the same, if user try to find the phone as 987-654-3210 he'll not find anything because user saved without dashed.

Is there anyway to make this search with something like

```
ilike(phone.replace("-", ""), paramsMap.phone.phone.replace("-", "") + "%")
```

This way it would work fine.

Someone know any way to replace dash before grails query?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I found here this solution:

```
 if (paramsMap.phone) {
                    String phoneNumber = paramsMap.phone.replace("-", "")
                    sqlRestriction("replace(phone, '-', '') like '%$phoneNumber%'")
                }
```

instead the

```
 if (paramsMap.phone) {
                    ilike('phone', paramsMap.phone + "%")
                }
```

This way I get my results all the time.